# Join tables, between column and attribute in xml data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm trying to make a query where I select all orders on a table, where the reference order number is the same as one of the values in an xml data type column.
Since I'm using this in a much larger scale query i need in this case a LEFT JOIN.

So let's say I have :

```
Table 1 :       id   |    reference_number
                 1         1001
                 2         37904
Table 2 :     Guid                                    |     XMLData        |    Messagge
           A1625F87-9F6F-45FC-B2EE-06CE0FF8EDA0                                    OK
         
This is my xml :
<MyOrders>
          <Order>  
            <FACI>600</FACI>
            <CUOR>Test Email</CUOR>
            <OREF>37904</OREF> // this is the number i need
            <Customer>
              <M3CUNO>US00860</M3CUNO>
            </Customer>
            <OrderLine>
              <ITNO>360007</ITNO>
              <ORQT>1</ORQT>
              <WHLO>60S</WHLO>
              <SAPR>50.0000</SAPR>
            </OrderLine>
          </Order>
</MyOrders>
```

Now I need to get the **message** field from table 2 and the **id** from table 1.
The **OREF** in xml must be the same as **reference_number** in table1
This is what I tried but I can't get that value.

```
select dbo.Table2.Message, dbo.Table1.id
from dbo.Table1 soh 
left join dbo.Table2 aq
on aq.XMLData.nodes.value('/MyOrders/Order/OREF') = soh.reference_number
```

Ofcourse this gives me this error :

> Remote function reference 'aq.XMLData.nodes.value' is not allowed, and the column name 'XMLData' could not be found or is ambiguous

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always provide a minimal reproducible example.

Assuming that the `reference_number` column is INTEGER data type.

**SQL**

```
...
on aq.XMLData.value('(/MyOrders/Order/OREF/text())[1]', 'INT') = soh.reference_number
```

SQL Fiddle: [T-SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdc34d/2)

Comment: Basically you're right but I didn't have the time to create a db fiddle, I'm sorry.Yes it's integer.  Anyway yuor query gives me all dataset null for table2. But I will make a further check right now. What does that `text()` do that you added?

Comment: Because there is no 'repro' I couldn't test it myself. `text()` is a peculiarity of SQL Server for performance reasons.

Comment: @Pavel, I created a fiddle. Check it out.